# Multiple client projects to one server project w/ Silverlight & RIA Services Beta

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

> The type or namespace name
>   'Resources' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'MyWebProject.Web'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\...\MySecondProject\Generated_Code\MyWebProject.Web.g.cs

I am having some problems trying to add a second SL client project to my (Ria services) SL Business Application. It has to do with the way the shared Resources files on the Web project are linked to from my new SL client project (the SL client project that was generated by the Business App template works fine). [The same problem was brought up in the SL forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/147057/327751.aspx#327751) but copying the Web folder from my existing SL client doesn't seem to work.

How can I add a second SL client project **using RIA services** to the solution of an existing SL Business Application without these problems over shared resources? Should I avoid the Business Application solution template for solutions with multiple SL clients since it seems to presume only a single client app will be sharing the resource files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it is still relevant, but I found your post while looking for a solution to the same problem of adding a second client. So if others come across the same issue, here it is.

I managed to fix it by adding a Web/Resources folder to my new client (Same structure as the template original project), and add the Resource files as **links** from the original Web project.

Right click > add > existing items... > navigate to .Web/Resources > select all the resource and designer stuff > **Add As Link** (in the Add dropdown).

Worked for me. Good Luck

LJ

Comment: Hi, yes that is also what I ended up doing. I had to either comment out or make static all the shared resources that were used in the Business Application template as that is what was causing my issues.